# How to make Javascript Execute after AJAX is called

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Okay, on one of my sites I have a "news" sidebar that displays events from a table.

I recently started using AJAX to make the table update by itself.

The AJAX worked for the most part, except for one thing...the time on each event didn't work. I was using JS to display the time.

The following is an example of one event...

```
<div class="event">
<p>The event text</p>
<script type="text/javascript">

//The timestamp variable below is fed by a PHP script from a big table of events. 
//Also keep in mind there are many events on the page!
document.write(get_time(1332900003));
</script>

</div>
```

So the problem is that AJAX grabs the HTML from the table, spits it out, but then the get_time function is not executed:( This worked fine before using AJAX, but not now.

So how can I make javascript execute after it is called by AJAX? I am using this AJAX script...

```
function updateNews()
{
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }


else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }


xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    if (document.getElementById("news").innerHTML != xmlhttp.responseText)
    {
    document.getElementById("news").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    }
  }


xmlhttp.open("GET","display2.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
updateNews();
setInterval( "updateNews()", 5000);
```

Thanks for the help!:)

Comment: forget this lib,  use jQuery instead. your life will be much easier.

Comment: Thanks...Jquery is a huge library though! Any ideas where I should start to simulate something like this...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying your HTML to following:

```
<div class="event">
    <p>The event text</p>
    <div id="showtime_xx"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("showtime_xx").innerHTML = get_time(1332900003);
    </script>
</div>
```

`document.write` makes things worst sometimes. Above code will makes sure it works all the time.

Comment: Also make sure to replace 'xx' with unique number so there won't be any ID conflict.

Comment: unfortunately, the javascript was still not executed:( I tried document.getElementById("showtime_xx").innerHTML = "test"; just to be sure, and it did not work.

Comment: You need to replace showtime_xx as showtime_01, showtime_02,... and so on... and use respective id in the js code

Comment: Yes I did, you guys can see for yourself. Here is the page being called: http://w3max.net/tagboard/display2.php and here is the page that displays the news: http://w3max.net/tagboard/display.php You can see that the javascript executes and displays the "test" text in the first one, but on the second one it never gets executed.

Comment: Can you set refresh interval to some higher value to fetch the data? say like 1 minute.

Comment: Hey Epuri, thanks for your help. I decided to use PHP though instead and just use relative dates. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery instead as commented above, your life will be much easier

```
$.post(url, {keyy: value}, function(){
    // this function will be called after ajax call
})
```

Comment: Okay thanks...but I am still not sure that helps me...(sorry I am very nooby at JS). There are about 30 events displayed so I would need the function to go several times? And also, my get_time function requires a timestamp parameter, which is given by PHP from the table of events.

Comment: maybe you can try this, `document.getElementById("news").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText + get_time(xxxxxxx);` on the your code, right after checkin the innerHTML if not the same as the ajax response.